# How to get a value of a session key value pair in Session_OnEnd() method

Tags: c#, session, session-variables, session-state

I have added a value of an Order using Session.Add("order",1) in Session so when user logs out I can unlock the order which I locked when user accessing it. Is there any other way to fire a database query when user logs out ? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your code in the [Session_End](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstatemodule.end.aspx) method, but **only** under the following condition:

> The Session_OnEnd event is only supported when the session-state
>   HttpSessionState.Mode property value is InProc, which is the default.
>   If the session-state Mode is set to StateServer or SQLServer, then the
>   Session_OnEnd event in the Global.asax file is ignored. If the session
>   state Mode property value is Custom, then support for the
>   Session_OnEnd event is determined by the custom session-state store
>   provider.

If you are using SQLServer or StateServer for session management - you can implement an HttpModule.

See the following for reference:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21156/ASP-NET-HttpModule-for-handling-session-end-with-S

http://www.ivan-nikolov.com/en/article/5/asp-net-session-state-mode-and-session-end-callback